# Cambiar propiedad de botón de un subform de otra clase del mismo plugin

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Dispongo de un proyecto, separado en varios plugins. Dentro de cada plugin tengo un .h y .cpp con métodos que son visibles al resto de clases de dicho plugin. Y luego un plugin general con funciones generales, que son visibles por todos los plugins.

Esta clase que comparte metodos el resto de plugins es la siguiente:

`pluginbl_formlock.h`

```
#include "bldebug.h"
#include "blpostgresqlclient.h"
#include "blmaincompany.h"
#include "blform.h"
#include "pdefs_pluginbl_formlock.h"


extern "C" PLUGINBL_FORMLOCK_EXPORT int entryPoint ( QMainWindow * );
extern "C" PLUGINBL_FORMLOCK_EXPORT int BlForm_load ( BlForm * );
extern "C" PLUGINBL_FORMLOCK_EXPORT int BlForm_DesBlForm ( BlForm * );
extern "C" PLUGINBL_FORMLOCK_EXPORT int BlForm_BlForm ( BlForm * );
extern "C" PLUGINBL_FORMLOCK_EXPORT int BlMainCompany_init ( BlMainCompany * );
```

Y su respectivo `pluginbl_formlock.cpp`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QAction>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QFile>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QPushButton>

#include "local_blI18n.h"
#include "pluginbl_formlock.h"
#include "blform.h"
#include "blmaincompany.h"
#include "bloqmenu.h"


///
/**
\param bcont
\return
**/
int entryPoint ( QMainWindow *bges )
{
    return ( 0 );
}

int BlMainCompany_init(BlMainCompany * main) {
    return 0;
}

/// Bloquear la ficha si no lo estaba ya por otro usuario
/**
  Antes, en "fichabloqueo" s&oacute;lo se almacenaba el nombre del campo identificador.
  Como al usar esquemas de PostgreSQL la nomenclatura "idtabla" no es exacta,
  pongo 'nombre_tabla.nombre_campo_id' en "fichabloqueo".
  As&iacute; identificamos inequ&iacute;vocamente lo que se ha bloqueado.
\param ficha
\return
**/
int BlForm_load ( BlForm *ficha )
{
    BL_FUNC_DEBUG

    if (ficha->fieldId().isEmpty()) return 0; // En listados editables o nuevas fichas no hacemos bloqueos

    QString table_dot_id = QString("%1.%2").arg(ficha->tableName()).arg(ficha->fieldId());
    QString query;

    query = "SELECT usuariobloqueo FROM bloqueo WHERE fichabloqueo = $1 AND identificadorfichabloqueo= $2 AND usuariobloqueo <> $3";
    BlDbRecordSet *cur1 = ficha->mainCompany()->load(query, table_dot_id, ficha->dbValue(ficha->fieldId()), ficha->mainCompany()->currentUser());
    if (!cur1->eof()) {
        QString nombre = cur1->value("usuariobloqueo").replace("CDI+", "");
        nombre = nombre.left(1).toUpper() + nombre.mid(1);
        g_s->msgInfo(_("%1 también tiene abierta esta ficha en estos momentos.\nSi ambos modifican un mismo dato, %1 perderá su cambio.").arg(nombre));
        BlForm_DesBlForm(ficha);
    }

    query = "INSERT INTO bloqueo (fichabloqueo, identificadorfichabloqueo, usuariobloqueo) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)";
    ficha->mainCompany()->run (query, table_dot_id, ficha->dbValue(ficha->fieldId()), ficha->mainCompany()->currentUser());

    delete cur1;
    return 0;
}


/// Dejar la ficha desbloqueada
/**
\param ficha
\return
**/
int BlForm_DesBlForm ( BlForm *ficha )
{
    BL_FUNC_DEBUG;

    if (!ficha->fieldId().isEmpty()) {
        if ( ficha->dbValue(ficha->fieldId()) != "") {

            QString table_dot_id = QString("%1.%2").arg(ficha->tableName()).arg(ficha->fieldId());

            QString query = "";
            if ( ficha->dbValue ( ficha->fieldId() ) != "" ) {
                QString usuario = "";
                BlDbRecordSet *cur = ficha->mainCompany()->loadQuery ( "SELECT current_user" );
                if ( !cur->eof() ) {
                    usuario = cur->value( "current_user" );
                } // end if
                delete cur;
                query = "SELECT * FROM bloqueo WHERE fichabloqueo = $1 AND identificadorfichabloqueo= $2 AND usuariobloqueo = $3";
                BlDbRecordSet *cur1 = ficha->mainCompany()->load( query ,
                                                                  table_dot_id,
                                                                  ficha->dbValue ( ficha->fieldId() ) ,
                                                                  usuario );
                if (!cur1->eof()) {
                    QString cond = QString("fichabloqueo = '%1' AND identificadorfichabloqueo = '%2'")
                            .arg(table_dot_id)
                            .arg(ficha->dbValue(ficha->fieldId()));

                    ficha->mainCompany()->runDelete("bloqueo", cond);
                }
                delete cur1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


///
/**
\param l
\return
**/
int BlForm_BlForm ( BlForm *l )
{
    BL_FUNC_DEBUG

    new BloqMenu ( l );

    /// Eliminar los bloqueos de usuarios no conectados (son restos de un cierre precipitado por alg&uacute;n fallo)
    QString cond = QString("usuariobloqueo NOT IN (SELECT usename FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = '%1');")
            .arg(l->mainCompany()->dbName());

    l->mainCompany()->runDelete("bloqueo", cond);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Del cual solo me interesa esta función:

```
int BlForm_load ( BlForm *ficha )
{
    BL_FUNC_DEBUG

    if (ficha->fieldId().isEmpty()) return 0; // En listados editables o nuevas fichas no hacemos bloqueos

    QString table_dot_id = QString("%1.%2").arg(ficha->tableName()).arg(ficha->fieldId());
    QString query;

    query = "SELECT usuariobloqueo FROM bloqueo WHERE fichabloqueo = $1 AND identificadorfichabloqueo= $2 AND usuariobloqueo <> $3";
    BlDbRecordSet *cur1 = ficha->mainCompany()->load(query, table_dot_id, ficha->dbValue(ficha->fieldId()), ficha->mainCompany()->currentUser());
    if (!cur1->eof()) {
        QString nombre = cur1->value("usuariobloqueo").replace("CDI+", "");
        nombre = nombre.left(1).toUpper() + nombre.mid(1);
        g_s->msgInfo(_("%1 también tiene abierta esta ficha en estos momentos.\nSi ambos modifican un mismo dato, %1 perderá su cambio.").arg(nombre));
        BlForm_DesBlForm(ficha);
    }

    query = "INSERT INTO bloqueo (fichabloqueo, identificadorfichabloqueo, usuariobloqueo) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)";
    ficha->mainCompany()->run (query, table_dot_id, ficha->dbValue(ficha->fieldId()), ficha->mainCompany()->currentUser());

    delete cur1;
    return 0;
}
```

Como podéis observar, cuando desde una clase del plugin, realizo un load, esta función detecta si hay un usuario leyendo la misma ficha, y avisa al siguiente usuario que entra que los cambios puede que no se guarden, debido que al final se guardan los datos de pantalla y se machacarán los datos con el último guardado, ya que no hay refresco en tiempo real.

Mi idea es a la vez que se muestre el aviso (para el segundo que entra), también se bloquee el botón de guardar y el subform de dicha ficha, para que hasta que no salga el que primero entró, y el segundo vuelva a entrar realizando otro load, no tenga habilitado el botón de guardar y el subform si no es el único que esta viendo esa ficha.

Tenia pensado en la función del aviso, poder acceder al objeto widget del botón guardar, así como a su mui_list(subformulario) de cualquier clase que invoque el método load, para así reutilizando esa función bloquear el subformulario y el botón.

Por lo que veo, debe ser con SLOTS, pero no me gusta ya que me tocaría ir clase por clase del mismo plugin, haciendo el connect signal/Slot.

¿Cómo podría desde la función BlForm_load, cambiar el estado de los widgets de esa ficha que llama al método load?

En plan:

```
    int BlForm_load ( BlForm *ficha )
    {
        BL_FUNC_DEBUG
    
        if (ficha->fieldId().isEmpty()) return 0; // En listados editables o nuevas fichas no hacemos bloqueos
    
        QString table_dot_id = QString("%1.%2").arg(ficha->tableName()).arg(ficha->fieldId());
        QString query;
    
        query = "SELECT usuariobloqueo FROM bloqueo WHERE fichabloqueo = $1 AND identificadorfichabloqueo= $2 AND usuariobloqueo <> $3";
        BlDbRecordSet *cur1 = ficha->mainCompany()->load(query, table_dot_id, ficha->dbValue(ficha->fieldId()), ficha->mainCompany()->currentUser());
        if (!cur1->eof()) {
            QString nombre = cur1->value("usuariobloqueo").replace("CDI+", "");
            nombre = nombre.left(1).toUpper() + nombre.mid(1);
            g_s->msgInfo(_("%1 también tiene abierta esta ficha en estos momentos.\nSi ambos modifican un mismo dato, %1 perderá su cambio.").arg(nombre));
            BlForm_DesBlForm(ficha);
        }
    
        query = "INSERT INTO bloqueo (fichabloqueo, identificadorfichabloqueo, usuariobloqueo) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)";
    
    
        ficha->mainCompany()->run (query, table_dot_id, ficha->dbValue(ficha->fieldId()), ficha->mainCompany()->currentUser());
    
    
-->  **ficha->mainCompany(). "mui_guardar"(nombre del objeto del botón de guardado) . setEnable(false) y lo mismo con el form/subform.**
    
        delete cur1;
        return 0;
    }
```

BlForm_load es una función que pertenece a una subclase de BLForm. "ficha" es una instancia de Blform. Son visibles a todas las clases que hereden de BlForm y BlSubform. Cuando hago ficha-> Puedo acceder a dbvalue del form/subform, pero no a los objetos del maincompany o del .ui como el boton guardar.

Cuando estoy en la clase tareaview.cpp/h/ con TareaViewBase(ui) Hedero de blform. Luego hago uso de la funcion Load para cargar los datos del subform. En ese momento es cuando pasa por BLForm_load para comprobar si hay un usuario con esa ficha abierta y salta el mensaje al usuario que entra segundo.

Quiero que cuando pase por BLform_load de paso que detecta un user en esa ficha, de paso, se bloquee el objeto mui_guardar y el subformulario mui_list.

Por ejemplo, tengo la clase tareaview.h/cpp con su TareaViewBase.ui. Que hereda de BlForm.  Ahi dispongo de mis widgets, y formularios, y la funcion load que carga los datos de la ficha. Si cuadno se realiza el load, hay un usuario dentro, salta Blform_load y muestra el aviso de que hay un usuario en al ficha, para visar que solo se contemplara el ultimo cambio. Mi idea es a la vez que se muestra el mensaje, bloquear el formulario y el boton de guardar (mui_list y mui_guardar).

```
tareaview.h

#ifndef TAREAVIEW_H
#define TAREAVIEW_H

#include "blwidget.h"
#include "blmaincompany.h"
#include "blform.h"
#include "blformlist.h"
#include "tsystem.h"
#include "blgenericcomboboxdelegate.h"
#include "bldatedelegate.h"
#include "blpicture.h"
#include "../plugin_pro/proyectoview.h"
#include "smtp.h"
#include "smtpssl.h"
#include "blhelp.h"
#include "pdefs_plugin_tar.h"
#include "blprogressbar.h"
#include <QElapsedTimer>

// Necesito definir un "fake" para que fichaPadre() se pueda declarar antes
class TareaView;

class PLUGIN_TAR_EXPORT TareaListProySubForm
      : public BlSubForm
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   TareaListProySubForm(QWidget *padre = 0);
   //bool prueba();


private:
   bool m_solapa_fin; ///< Si es true, se mostrarán las tareas finalizadas y descartadas, si es false, las activas, revisar y en curso
protected:
   TareaView *fichaPadre()
   {
       TareaView *fp = (TareaView *)parent()->parent()->parent();
       if (fp == NULL) g_s->msgError("No se pudo localizar la ficha de tareas desde el listado.");
       return fp;
   }
public slots:
   virtual void load(QString id_proyecto = "", QString tareas_anteriores ="");
   void cambio_de_fecha_entrega(QString);

};

#include "ui_tareabase.h"

/** Ventana de ficha de asunto.
    Se encarga de la presentacion de la ficha de asunto y del tratamiento de eventos producidos
    en dicha ventana.
**/
class PLUGIN_TAR_EXPORT TareaView
      : public BlForm
      , public Ui::TareaBase
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   TareaView(BlMainCompany *, QWidget *, QString vienefasepedido = 0 );
   virtual int cargarPost(QString);
   virtual int save();


protected:
   void btSetCheckedNoSignalAndDisabled(QTabWidget *bt, bool c) { btSetCheckedNoSignal(bt, c); bt->setEnabled(!c); }
   void btSetCheckedNoSignal(QTabWidget *bt, bool c) { bt->blockSignals(true);  bt->setCurrentIndex(c); bt->blockSignals(false); }
   QString calcularFechaEntregaTarPedidos(int incremento_dias);
   QString totalTareasSeccion(int id_secci);


private:
   static const int MAX_REPES; ///< Límite de secciones repetidas activas de un mismo solicitante

   bool m_enviando;

   bool m_enviando_email_ProdProtoMadera;
   bool m_enviando_email_Proto_EnCurso;

   QString m_id_proyecto;
   QString m_id_tipo;
   QString n_sub;
   QList<BlDbSubFormRecord *> *m_listProtoNuevos; // Tareas nuevas de prototipos sobre las que avisar
   QList<BlDbSubFormRecord *> *m_listBocetoNuevos; // Tareas nuevas de bocetos sobre las que avisar
   QString SMTP_S;
   QString SMTP_E;
   QString SMTP_P;

private slots:
   void on_mui_carpetas_activated(int);
   void on_mui_id_secci_activated(int);
   void on_mui_id_prioridad_valueChanged();


   void pasaArticulo_slot();
   void crearPedido_slot();
   void crearPendientePedido_slot();


   void avisarSolicitanteRevisar_slot();
   void tarPresuModal_slot(bool es_presu_agrupado, bool es_presu_detallado);
   void avisar_asignado_slot();

   void agregarTextoObservaciones(QString);

   void on_mui_imprimir_observaciones_clicked();
   void on_mui_bt_ver_proto_clicked();

   void on_mui_list_clicked(const QModelIndex &index);
   void on_mui_num_orden_textChanged(const QString &arg1);
   void on_mui_todas_tareas_clicked(bool checked);
};

#endif
```

tareaview.cpp

Aqui primero paso por el contructor:

```
TareaView::TareaView(BlMainCompany *comp, QWidget *padre, QString vienefasepedido) // crear variable para ver si viene de tareas o de pedidos (Boton)
    : BlForm(comp, padre),
      m_enviando_email_al_solicitante(false),
      m_enviando_email_al_asignado(false),
      m_enviando_email_numero_orden(false),
      m_enviado_email_revisar_presu(false),
      m_enviando_email_solicitanteF(false),
      m_enviando_email_MADERA(false),
      m_enviando_email_META(false),
      m_enviando_email_METAL(false),
      m_enviando_email_PINTURA(false),
      m_enviando_email_DECORACION(false),
      m_enviando_email_HIDRO(false),
      m_enviando_email_ProdProtoMadera(false),
      m_enviando_email_Proto_EnCurso(false),
      m_enviando_email_solicitante(false),
      m_enviando_email_CDI(false),
      m_enviando_email_ruta(false),
      m_enviando_email_detallar(false),
      m_enviando_email_secciones(false),
      es_lista_pedido(vienefasepedido)
{
    BL_FUNC_DEBUG; //

    m_listProtoNuevos = new QList<BlDbSubFormRecord *>();
    m_listBocetoNuevos = new QList<BlDbSubFormRecord *>();

    /*SMTP_S = "smtp.ionos.es";
    SMTP_E = "hilex@hilex.eu";
    SMTP_P = "ch8hc0c";*/

    SMTP_S = "smtp.ionos.es";
    SMTP_E = "noreply@hilex.eu";
    SMTP_P = "@9cJa^$hx!tGM9Fg";

    try {
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        setupUi(this);
        buscarWidgetsForm();
        mui_list->setMainCompany(comp);
        // Si un día queremos ficha de solo lectura: if (!g_syst->empleadoPuedeXXX()) setSelectMode();();
        activarDeteccionCambiosCampos();

        mui_bt_ver_proto->setVisible(false);
        mui_todas_tareas->setChecked(false);

        setDbTableName("pro.proyecto_con_cliente_sector_estado__vista");

        addDbField("id", BlDbField::DbInt, BlDbField::DbPrimaryKey, _("Id proyecto"));
        setDbFieldId("id");
        addDbField("id_proyecto_padre", BlDbField::DbInt, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Id proyecto padre"));

        addDbField("cliente", BlDbField::DbVarChar, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Cliente"));
        addDbField("cod", BlDbField::DbInt, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Cód."));
        addDbField("cod_completo", BlDbField::DbVarChar, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Cód. proyecto"));
        addDbField("concepto", BlDbField::DbVarChar, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Concepto"));
        addDbField("imagen", BlDbField::DbVarChar, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Imagen"));
        addDbField("id_estado", BlDbField::DbInt, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Id estado"));
        addDbField("id_empleado", BlDbField::DbInt, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Id responsable pro"));
        addDbField("empleado", BlDbField::DbVarChar, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Responsable pro"));
        addDbField("id_tipo", BlDbField::DbInt, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Tipo Proyecto"));
        addDbField("total_subproyectos_activos", BlDbField::DbInt, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Subpro_acti"));
        addDbField("cod_power", BlDbField::DbInt, BlDbField::DbNothing, _("Cód. Power"));


        // Buscador de secciones en lista desplegable
        // La configuramos aquí, pero no conviene darle valores: necesita sabes
        // el proyecto concreto y hay muchísimos registros en la vista de secciones disponibles
        mui_id_secci->setMainCompany(mainCompany());
        mui_id_secci->setFieldId("id");
        mui_id_secci->m_valores["concepto"] = "";
        //mui_id_secci->m_valores["necesita_fecha_entrega"] = "";
        //mui_id_secci->setFieldValue(es_proto);
        mui_id_secci->setAllowNull(true);


        // Poner las carpetas disponibles para el proyecto
        mui_carpetas->insertItems(1, ProyectoView::carpetas_proyecto(mainCompany()));
        mui_carpetas->setCurrentIndex(0);
        mui_proto_ver->hide();
        mui_borrar->setVisible(false);

        mui_proyecto->setIcon(g_s->logoEmpresa());

        pintar();

        // Antes de activar el control de cambios, definir qué campos no se deben verificar
        // Esto es así debido a que esta ficha tiene campos de sólo lectura y otros que
        // sólo toman su valor desde la lista de tareas
        dialogChanges_setExcludedObject(mui_cliente);

      
        dialogChanges_setExcludedObject(mui_num_orden);
        dialogChanges_readValues();

        gb_num_orden->setVisible(false);

        // Detectar cambios del usuario en campos de la tabla
        connect(mui_list, SIGNAL(cambios(int, int)), this, SLOT(edicion_list(int, int)));

        // Forzar deshabilitación de botones, ya que en principio no habrá tarea seleccionada
        on_mui_list_currentCellChanged(-1, -1, -1, -1);

        resaltarCambiosEnBotones(false);

    } catch(...) {
        g_s->msgError(_("No se pudo abrir la ficha %1.").arg(metaObject()->className()), this);
    }
}
```

Luego la funcion Cargarpost:

```
// Acciones a realizar tras cargar la ficha
/**
\param id Identificador de proyecto
   \return 0 si no hubo problemas
   Actualiza el listado de secciones disponibles para el proyecto (sólo puede haber una tarea activa de cada sección).
   Luego actualiza el listado de tareas.
**/
int TareaView::cargarPost(QString id)
{
    BL_FUNC_DEBUG;
    m_id_proyecto = id;

    if(g_s->esCDI() && (g_s->getIdEmpleado() == 86 || g_s->getIdEmpleado() == 106)) mui_gro_tarea_activa->setMaximumWidth(600);

    m_listProtoNuevos->clear();
    m_listBocetoNuevos->clear();
    cargarIdSecci();

    mui_proto_iniciar->hide();
    mui_proto_ver->hide();

    // Poner en el listado las tareas del proyecto actual
    mui_list->load(m_id_proyecto,"FALSE");

    mui_id_prioridad->setCurrentIndex(dbValue("id_prioridad").toInt());

    mui_prev_imagen->load_picture(dbValue("imagen"));

    // Actualizar el título de la ventana
    QString titul;
    if(vienedePedido()=="0"){
    titul = _("Tareas del proyecto \"%1: %2\"")
            .arg(dbValue("cod_completo"))
            .arg(dbValue("concepto"));
    label_tit->setText("TAREAS DEL PROYECTO");

    }else{
    titul = _("Fases de Pedidos del proyecto \"%1: %2\"")
                .arg(dbValue("cod_completo"))
                .arg(dbValue("concepto"));
    label_tit->setText("FASES DE PEDIDO DEL PROYECTO");
    }
    mainCompany()->removeWindow(window());
    setTitleName(titul);
    mainCompany()->insertWindow(titul.replace(' ', '_').replace('"','_'), this, false, titul);
    return 0;
}
```

Y luego desde el cargarpost llamo a la funcion load del subdform:

```
/// Pone los registros de la vista de PostgreSQL en el listado
/**
  \param id_proyecto
**/
void TareaListProySubForm::load(QString id_proyecto,QString tareas_anteriores)
{
    BL_FUNC_DEBUG;

    if(g_s->esCDI() && (g_s->getIdEmpleado() == 86 || g_s->getIdEmpleado() == 106)) {m_anchs[11]= 100; m_anchs[15]= 130; m_anchs[18]= 100;};

    setSortingEnabled(false);
    if (id_proyecto.isEmpty()) {
        id_proyecto = fichaPadre()->dbValue("id");
        //QString id_tipo = fichaPadre()->dbValue("id_tipo");
        //g_s->msgError(id_tipo);
    }

    // Mostrar las tareas finalizadas y descartadas
    QString cond_estado;

    if (!fichaPadre()->solapaActivasSeleccionada()) {
        if(tareas_anteriores=="FALSE") cond_estado += " AND (id_estado = 3 OR id_estado = 4) AND date_part('year', semana) >= date_part('year', current_date - interval '1 year')"; // finalizadas y descartadas
        else cond_estado += " AND (id_estado = 3 OR id_estado = 4)";
    }
    else {
        cond_estado += " AND (id_estado <> 3 AND id_estado <> 4)";
    }

   QString filtro_pedido;

   if(fichaPadre()->vienedePedido()=="0")
       filtro_pedido = QString (" AND es_tarea_proyecto = TRUE"); // FILTRADO TAREAS PROYECTO
   else
       filtro_pedido = QString (" AND es_tarea_pedido = TRUE");   // FILTRADO TAREAS PEDIDO

   if(fichaPadre()->dbValue("cod_completo").length() >14)  filtro_pedido = QString (" ");

   if(fichaPadre()->mui_tab_tareas->currentIndex()==1)
       filtro_pedido = QString (" ");


   //ordenamos por id primero ya que al ser coorelativas las tareas es necesario para que no se desordenen
    QString consulta = QString("SELECT * FROM %1 WHERE %2 %3 %4 ORDER BY id,semana")
            .arg(tableName())
            .arg("id_proyecto = " + id_proyecto)
            .arg(cond_estado)
            .arg(filtro_pedido);

    //g_s->msgErrorConsole(consulta,0);

    bool primera_carga = (columnCount() == 0);

    BlSubForm::load(consulta);

    if (primera_carga)
        conf_tabla(m_anchs, columnNumber("id"), Qt::AscendingOrder); //ordenamos por id primero ya que al ser coorelativas las tareas es necesario para que no se desordenen

    QHash<QString, QString> colores;
    colores.insert("2", "#FF5050"); // Revisar: rojo
    colores.insert("3", "#50FF50"); // Finalizada: verde
    colores.insert("4", "#E0E0E0"); // Descartada: gris
    colores.insert("5", "#FFFF50"); // En curso: amarillo
    colores.insert("6", "#FF2BEC"); // Modificar: violeta suabe
    colores.insert("7", "#007FFF"); // Listo: Azul
    colorear("id_estado", colores, columnNumber("_estado"));

    mui_list->setItemDelegateForColumn(columnNumber("semana"), new BlDateDelegate(mainCompany(), this, false));

    BlDateDelegate *delegado_fecha_entrega = new BlDateDelegate(mainCompany(), this, true);
    delegado_fecha_entrega->initialize("fecha_entrega");
    connect(delegado_fecha_entrega, SIGNAL(currentValueChangedByUser(QString)), this, SLOT(cambio_de_fecha_entrega(QString)));
    mui_list->setItemDelegateForColumn(columnNumber("fecha_entrega"), delegado_fecha_entrega);

    BlDateDelegate *delegado_fecha_prevista = new BlDateDelegate(mainCompany(), this, true);
    delegado_fecha_prevista->initialize("fecha_prevista");
    connect(delegado_fecha_prevista, SIGNAL(currentValueChangedByUser(QString)), this, SLOT(cambio_de_fecha_prevista(QString)));
    mui_list->setItemDelegateForColumn(columnNumber("fecha_prevista"), delegado_fecha_prevista);

    BlGenericComboBoxDelegate *cbd_est = new BlGenericComboBoxDelegate(mainCompany(), this);
    cbd_est->set_foreign_table("tar.estado", "id", "concepto");
    cbd_est->set_foreign_field(columnNumber("id_estado"), "id_estado");

    if(fichaPadre()->mui_tab_tareas->currentIndex()==1){ // SI PESTAÑA 'NO ACTIVAS', ESTADOS FINALIZADO, MODIFICAR o DESCARTADA
        //cbd_est->set_where_condition("id =3 OR id = 4 OR id = 6");
        //cbd_est->set_where_condition_solo_si("id =3 OR id = 4 OR id = 6", "id_secci", 2, false);
        cbd_est->set_where_condition_solo_si("(id =3 OR id = 4 OR id = 2)", "id_secci", 2, true);

    }
    //else{
    //    cbd_est->set_where_condition_solo_si("id != 3", "id_empleado_solicitante", g_s->getIdEmpleado().toInt(), false);
    //

// Si el solicitante no es el empleado actual, ocultar estado "Finalizada"
// De momento, Navarro se dio cuenta de que no sirve este filtro:
// cbd_est->set_where_condition_solo_si("id != 3", "id_empleado_solicitante", g_s->getIdEmpleado().toInt(), false);

    cbd_est->setAllowNull(false);
    cbd_est->initialize("_estado");
    connect(cbd_est, SIGNAL(currentValueChangedByUser(QString)), this, SLOT(cambio_de_estado(QString)));
    mui_list->setItemDelegateForColumn(columnNumber("_estado"), cbd_est);

    BlGenericComboBoxDelegate *cbd_empl = new BlGenericComboBoxDelegate(mainCompany(), this);
    cbd_empl->set_foreign_table("gen.empleado", "id", "nombre");
    cbd_empl->set_foreign_field(columnNumber("id_empleado"), "id_empleado");

    if(fichaPadre()->vienedePedido()=="0")     cbd_empl->set_where_condition("activo AND asig_tar");
    else     cbd_empl->set_where_condition("activo AND asig_pedido");

    cbd_empl->initialize("_empleado");
    mui_list->setItemDelegateForColumn(columnNumber("_empleado"), cbd_empl);

    // Si el proyecto tiene artículos multicliente, habilitar selección de variante cliente
    QString cons = QString("SELECT id FROM pro.proyecto_rel_cli WHERE id_proyecto = %1 LIMIT 1").arg(id_proyecto);
    BlDbRecordSet *reg = mainCompany()->loadQuery(cons);
    if (!(reg == NULL || reg->eof())) {
        TareaView *ficha_padre = (TareaView *)parentWidget()->parentWidget()->parentWidget();
        BlGenericComboBoxDelegate *cbd_clv = new BlGenericComboBoxDelegate(mainCompany(), this);
        cbd_clv->set_foreign_table("pro.proyecto_rel_cli__vista", "id", "variante_cliente_nombre");
        cbd_clv->set_foreign_field(columnNumber("id_proyecto_rel_cli"), "id_proyecto_rel_cli");
        cbd_clv->set_where_condition("id_proyecto = " + ficha_padre->getIdProyecto());
        cbd_clv->initialize("_cliente_variante_pro");
        mui_list->setItemDelegateForColumn(columnNumber("_cliente_variante_pro"), cbd_clv);
        m_anchs[11]= 100; m_anchs[15]= 20; m_anchs[18]= 200;

    }
    else {
        setColumnVisible("_cliente_variante_pro", false);
        setColumnVisible("variante_pro", false);
    }

    setEditMode();

    if (((BlForm *)parent())->editMode()) setEditMode();
    else setSelectMode();
```

}

La cosa es que desde BlForm_load, si que accedo a los datos de la BD y de las variables de tareaview, pero no a los widgets graficos y sus propiedades. Me gustaria ademas de que saliera el mensaje, bloquear objetos.

gracias

Comment: Siento las molestias por la anterior publicacion mal formulada. Att

Comment: Gracias por la edición, mis disculpas.

Comment: Sería necesario saber cómo y dónde están declarados los elementos que quieres modificar desde `BlForm_load`. También sería interesante saber si `ficha` es una instancia de una subclase de `BlForm` o si es una instancia de `BlForm` directamente

Comment: BlForm_load es una función que pertenece a una subclase de BLForm. Ficha es una instancia de Blform. Son visibles a todas las clases que hereden de BlForm y BlSubform. Cuando hago ficha-> Puedo acceder a dbvalue del form/subform, pero no a los objetos del maincompany o del .ui como el boton guardar.  Cuando estoy en la clase tareaview.cpp/h/ con TareaViewBase(ui) Hedero de blform. Luego hagouso de la funcion Load para cargar los datos del subform. En ese momento es cuando pasa por BLForm_load para comprobar si hay un usuario con esa ficha abierta y salta el mensaje al usuario que entra segundo

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y añade la información que falta. No has indicado qué elementos necesitas modificar ni dónde se encuentran

Comment: Hecho... tiene que ser una tonteria, igual tengo que declarar en BlForm_load un objeto de tipo Button generico, para que lo identifique en cada blform/subform, tengan estos boton o no. Lo que no quiero es un slot/signal por clase que tenga metodo load, me gustaria hacerlo generico.

Comment: A ver no, meter código por meterlo no sirve de nada. Borra todo lo que no sea necesario. Hace falta saber dónde está declarados los dos objetos que dices (supongo que será en `BlForm`, así que falta la declaración de esa clase **solo** con esos dos miembros y su visibilidad, el resto de la clase sobra). Si luego estás empleando una subclase como es `TareaView`, perfecto, pon su declaración, pero en vez de poner **todo**, eliminas todo lo que no sea la herencia y detalles que afecten a los objetos que nos interesan.